# How can I write a Func without Lambde expression?

Tags: c#, anonymous-function, lambda

I am just thinking how to convert this:
`List.Where(X=>X>5);` to non-lambda expression code.
I cannot figure out how to get Func working here.

Comment: Why would u want that ?

Comment: Just to to know how to do that, nothing els :) I have started to forget stuff..

Comment: you can put there any method that takes in one parameter of your input type and returns `bool`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two reasonably simple possibilities for creating delegates without using lambda expressions:

- Write a method and use a method group conversion

  ```
  private static bool GreaterThan5(int x)
  {
      return x > 5;
  }

  ...

  var query = list.Where(GreaterThan5);
  ```
- Use an anonymous method

  ```
  var query = list.Where(delegate(int x) { return x > 5; });
  ```

Neither of those are as clear as using a lambda expression though. For more complicated examples where you actually want to capture local variables, the "write a separate method" version would get a lot more complicated.

Answer (score 3):

While I don't understand the purpose of this, you can do it like this:

```
bool MyFilterFunction(int x)
{
    return x > 5;
}
```

Then rewrite your code:

```
List.Where(MyFilterFunction);
```

Comment: Yep but I was thinking about anonymous function without an "external" delegate.

Comment: @Jon Skeet already answered this. I can't say it better =). Only add that using local variables in lambda would convert in not just a lot more complicated but complete waste of time and you should use lambda whenever possible.